# setAlarmClock() fires alarm repeatedly [issue turned out to be due to a Spinner]

Tags: android, android-alarms, setalarmclock

EDIT for my solution: I was using a Spinner drop down list to set the time for the alarm and forgot that the `onSelectItem` method of a Spinner constantly considers itself selected, so by placing the alarm in within that method, it constantly fired. OP Below

I'm attempting to make a daily notification system. I'm using `AlarmManager` to push the notification at a given time, and according to the documentation, I'm using methods that should just fire an alarm once. However, the alarm is repeatedly fired until I kill the app altogether.

Here's my initialization stuff:

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

alarmInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

and my `AlarmReceiver` class:

```
import static com.example.umbrellareminder.MainActivity.location_button;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context context;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        location_button.performClick();
    }
}
```

(`location_button` is what I use to run an http request and push the notification)

Now to actually fire the alarm, I've tried both

```
alarmMgr.setAlarmClock(alarmInfo,alarmIntent);
```

and

```
alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),alarmIntent);
```

However, they both run repeatedly. I also tried adding a  time delay then including `alarmIntent.cancel()`, which does cancel the alarm, but it cancels the alarm before it can fire at all (which is confusing, would have figured it would do that after the time delay)

So is there any reason I'm missing why this alarm is repeatedly firing?

Editing to add additional info: I have a button that is used to make an http request/get some info to display and use for the notification. The alarm itself is set within a `Spinner` (the drop down list is a list of optional times for the alarm), in the `onItemSelectedListener` like so:

```
Spinner time_list = findViewById(R.id.time_list);
        time_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                remind_time = time_list.getSelectedItem().toString();

                int hour = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(remind_time.charAt(0)));
                int minute = Integer.parseInt(remind_time.substring(2,3));

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 45);

                if(cal.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()){
                    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                }

                Log.d("TIME",cal.getTime().toString());
                alarmInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

                //line where I set the alarm
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,alarmIntent);
            }
```

Comment: Those are indeed one-shot alarms. You mention that you're making a daily alarm. Have you implemented that yet? That is, are you possibly setting the next alarm again too soon after it fires for the previous time?

Comment: Actually just realized my mistake in using either of those, and switched to ```setRepeating```, but the issue remains. I'm using an interval of a day. So I'm not setting any alarm a second time, just the one call to setRepeating.

Comment: OK. What do you mean by repeatedly, exactly? Does the `Notification` appear again immediately after you dismiss it? Where are you setting the alarm? Is it in `location_button`'s `OnClickListener`?

Comment: So repeatedly as in I have a function called to make an http request when the alarm fires, and it fires multiple times a second because I have log outputs telling me when a request is made. So for whatever reason, I fire an alarm, it calls the function behind the button from my OP, and then does that multiple times per second. Notification does indeed reappear the instant I dismiss it. I'll answer the other two questions with a post edit

Comment: The only thing I see there that can cause an inadvertent alarm set is the `OnItemSelectedListener`, which will actually run once automatically upon the first UI layout. Have you determined for certain that `AlarmReceiver` is running repeatedly? Have you put a log there, too?

Comment: Ah nuts yeah that was it. Thanks much! Keep forgetting it constantly considers an item as selected...if you add that as an answer, I'll check it as accepted

Comment: Ah, cool. No problem. I'm good, though. :-) Nothing major. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you'd like, or to just delete this, if you'd rather. Thanks, anyway. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!